# it was only compounding a felony

Tags: meaning, british-english

> Poor crazy Cissie, my Nurse that I was telling you of, 
>   she took three solid silver tablespoons.' 'Took! But isn't that
>   stealing?' Una cried. 'Hsh!' said Philadelphia, looking round at Puck.
>   'All I say is she took them without my leave.  I made it right
>   afterwards. So, as Dad says--and he's a magistrate-, it wasn't a legal
>   offence; **it was only compounding a felony**.

This is from  "Marklake Witches" by Kipling.
http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf

What does "only" mean here ?

Does "compounding" mean  "there is possibility of being a felony"  ?

I am glad if some one  kindly teach me.

Comment: "Only" here takes its common meaning of _merely_ or _no more than._ Did you consult a dictionary to learn about the verb _to compound?_ Please see [**this link.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compounding_a_felony) See also definition 10 in the [**Collins Dictionary.**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/compound)

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have never heard of this phrase definition in the US. When I first read the example, I thought it was "6. to intensify by an added element ⇒ *his anxiety was compounded by her crying*", except that would make no sense in this context. But I can see how it might be confusing. Anyway you should write an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have understood the meaning of  "compounding a felony" so well.

Answer (score 2):

The author Rudyard Kipling here uses the verb *to compound* in its special legal sense.

See [*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913),*](http://lexicon.x10host.com/?w=compound) definition 5 under *verb*:

> 5. To settle amicably; to adjust by agreement; to compromise; to discharge from obligation upon terms different from those which were stipulated; as, to compound a debt. *I pray, my lords, let me compound this strife.* Shakespeare. *To compound a felony,* to accept of a consideration for forbearing to prosecute, such compounding being an indictable offense.

The more modern [*Collins Dictionary*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/compound) still has under definition 10:

> 10. *law* to agree not to prosecute in return for a consideration *⇒ to compound a crime*

In law, an officer of the court (a magistrate, judge or attorney, e.g.) may agree not to prosecute a crime in return for some consideration. In this case, the nurse Cissie purloined three silver tablespoons, but Philadelphia (the speaker in your quotation) "made it right," and as a result Cissie was not punished for the theft.

The adverb *only* is used here in its normal sense as *merely* or *no more than.*

Comment: Thank so much for your detailed answer!  It is so helpful!

Comment: Hi. You could also include the definition and link to Collins to show that it is a definition still in a modern dictionary. That would seem to me to make an even better answer, especially since you've already indicated that info in a comment.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Good point - I originally used the Collins citation, but replaced it with Webster; I'll include both, belt & suspenders. (Chambers has it too, btw, and Oxford, who call it _dated._)

Comment: I actually did not know this use of *compound*.